# Scraping game by game stats from nhl.com in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to get data for game by game stats for NHL for particular dates.

The following link has the first page of stats for 28/02 to 30/03:

http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=teamsummary&reportType=game&startDate=2016-02-28&endDate=2017-03-30&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,wins

I try the following code in R and get an output that is huge and may contain the data but not in a concise table format.

```
library(XML)
url <- paste("http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=teamsummary&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20162017&seasonTo=20162017&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,wins", sep = "")
htmlParse(getURL(url))
```

How can I scrape this effectively so that I can get the data in a table for the range of dates?

Comment: IANAL, but the terms of use prohibit scraping the website content: "[You may not] engage in unauthorized spidering, scraping, or harvesting of content or information, or use any other unauthorized automated means to compile information."
https://www.nhl.com/info/terms-of-service?navid=drippan

Comment: But if you want to learn more about how to pick a table out of a harvested web page, this guide might be useful... https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Comment: Originally posted by @brownshoes as an answer: "Try this package. You can use it to scrape games or seasons https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nhlscrapr/nhlscrapr.pdf"